# Select some photos from witnin an album and Create a url to share them using Google Photo APIs

Tags: google-photos

I managed to create a Google Photo Album and upload many photos to this album using the Google Photo API.

I need also using Google Photo API again, to select only a couple of these photos and create a url in order to share this.

I would appreciate any help,
Nick

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking, your question lacks of information and seems like you want SO to make job for you. Please update the question - what have you tried so far? What Exactly is your problem while implementing the solution?

Comment: I have written that "I managed to create a Google Photo Album "
I have written that "I managed to … upload many photos to this album using the Google Photo API. "
I do not know how to "select only a couple of these photos and create a url in order to share this." using the Google Photo APIs.

Comment: It can be done in many ways it tells nothing - where is code request or whatever?